# local inversion

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R^n}$ for $n \ge 3$ be a bounded domain with smooth boundary and let $\alpha \in (0,1)$  and $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $f \in C^{0, \alpha}(\bar \Omega)$, the boundary value problem
$$-\Delta u+\lambda u=h$$ on $\Omega$ , $$u=0$$  on $ \partial\Omega$

has unique solution $u$ in $C^{2,\alpha}(\bar \Omega)$. Then show that there exists $\epsilon, \eta$ such that $\forall h \in C^{0,\alpha}(\bar \Omega)$ such that $||h||_{C^{0,\alpha}(\bar \Omega)}< \epsilon$ and $||u||_{C^{0,\alpha}(\bar \Omega)}< \eta$
there exists a unique $u$ in $C^{2,\alpha}(\bar \Omega)$
$$ -\Delta u + \lambda u -u^{\epsilon}=h $$ on $\Omega$

$$u=0 $$ on $\partial\Omega $

I'm not really sure what to do here although I sense the local inverse theorem is the way to go.
Thoughts?

Here is a picture about the theorem:
[image]

Comment: Can you state the local inverse theorem? Also, what is $s$ in the equation to be solved? I'd also love to know which book or notes you are studying from, because I very much enjoy the subject you seem to be studying i.e. PDE.

Comment: I made an edit Teresa. I'm using Ambrosetti's Nonlinear Analysis and semilinear elliptic equations

Comment: I will get that book right away from somewhere, @Jama. You may have just given me something very useful to read for the next few years. I cannot thank you enough personally. I will take a look at this question and see what I can do. And +1 for your participation, highly appreciate you taking the time to reply.

Comment: Thank you for your kind words but I don't think I did much haha. I'd be happy to send you the book if you haven't found it yet.

Comment: I found it, thank you for asking. I just don't know how to work it out exactly, although just like you I believe that the local inverse theorem is involved. Also, you know me and PDE : I read a lot of the book just for fun, before I decided to look for your question.

Comment: Oh great. Ok no problem. If I figure it out I'll let you know.

Comment: Thanks. I was actually looking for something that would challenge my knowledge of functional analysis, especially Sobolev spaces. Anyway, we will get to the bottom of this together. Just want to say : for some time I will be doing some other work, so I may take some time to reply and work on this.

Comment: Ok. Yes, same here but we'll get it done.

Comment: I struggled a little with the notation and all, so I'm not able to write an answer. There seems to be an $f$ then an $h$, and there seem to be two $\epsilon$s. I feel like this question has something to do with the open mapping theorem for maps between Banach spaces . Can you direct me to where this question of yours can be found? I could not find it in Ambrosetti, although I could find Theorem 1.14 and equation 1.8 concerning it.

Comment: It's not  in the book :(. It's a problem an instructor gave me to think about.

Comment: Ok. So we need to use the local inversion theorem. It basically says that if h (the data) is small then the solution will be small. So we need to check F'(u) at u=0 is invertible. F(u)= $\Delta u+\lambda u-u^p$. If you take this derivative and evaluate at 0 you $\Delta+\lambda h$ We want to show that this is invertible but we actually have this for me since this is the same as $\Delta+\lambda h=k$ having a solution and it is a hypothesis of the problem.  So the conditions of the local inversion theorem have satisfied and the conclusion follows.

Comment: Ah, I see! You can put that as an answer. I had some thoughts regarding surjective operators (which the first line creates) and how they form an open sets in the Banach space of operators between two Banach spaces. But that does not completely materialize, because I could not quite get my head around the fact that the second operator needs to be in the same space as the first. So I abandoned it. Anyway, I'll continue reading Ambrosetti. I will see your answer as well, I'd love to.